# How to display images in a flipview from SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, uwp

I want to display images saved in SQL server management studio in FlipView using Universal Windows Platform. The data type for the Image is `nvarchar` using Image Path.

I've put in image url in the last record to test out if my code actually goes through the database.

[image: database table]

And it does!
It just displays the last record which is an image url:

[image: output]

So i don't know why it cannot display the images that's saved in the database using image path. Pls help! Also, apologies if my coding doesn't make sense. I'm very new to programming :/

MainPage.html:

```
<FlipView x:Name="TheFlipView" SelectionChanged="DisplayedItemChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-117,66,0,0"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Height="1000" Width="1392">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10">
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Top"   Source="{Binding ImgPath}" 

                       Stretch="Fill" Margin="123,0,0,0" Width="1269" Height="899" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace TMD_Display.Views
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private string connectionString = @"Server=LAPTOP-IQQCR1C1\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SampleDB;User Id=alish;Password=polylife16;";

        //Make a place to store the timer
        private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer;

        //Make a place to store the last time the displayed item was set
        private DateTime _lastChange;
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string ImgPath { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Configure the timer
            _timer = new DispatcherTimer
            {
                //Set the interval between ticks (in this case 2 seconds to see it working)
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
            };

            //Change what's displayed when the timer ticks
            _timer.Tick += ChangeImage;
            //Start the timer
            _timer.Start();
        }

        protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            var images = await GetImagesAsync();

            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Models.Images>> GetImagesAsync()
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                var images = await conn.QueryAsync<Models.Images>(
                    @"SELECT ImgId As Id,ImgPath 
                    FROM ImageSave");
                TheFlipView.ItemsSource = images;
                //This is the code to be changed
                return images;
            }
        }

        private void ChangeImage(object sender, object o)
        {
            //Get the number of items in the flip view
            //var totalItems = TheFlipView.Items.Count;

            var totalItems = TheFlipView.Items.Count;
            //Figure out the new item's index (the current index plus one, if the next item would be out of range, go back to zero)
            var newItemIndex = (TheFlipView.SelectedIndex + 1) % totalItems;

            //Set the displayed item's index on the flip view
            TheFlipView.SelectedIndex = newItemIndex;
        }

        private void DisplayedItemChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Show the time deltas...
            var currentTime = DateTime.Now;

            if (_lastChange != default(DateTime))
            {
                TimeDelta.Text = (currentTime - _lastChange).ToString();
            }

            _lastChange = currentTime;

            //Since the page is configured before the timer is, check to make sure that we've actually got a timer
            if (!ReferenceEquals(_timer, null))
            {
                _timer.Stop();
                _timer.Start();
            }
       }
  }
```

Image.cs:

```
namespace TMD_Display.Models
{
    public class Image
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        //public string Name { get; set; }

        //public DateTime FirstAppearance { get; set; }

        public string ImgPath { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where're the images? Did you put the images in the 'Assets/Images/' folder of the projects?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I did put :)

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Is there a way I can direct the Binding ImgPath to the Images folder?

Answer (score 0):

Although your Binding code is incomplete, but I judged that the problem was not in the binding code. You might not know that UWP app has application data folder and installation folder. If you put the images in the 'Assets/Images/' folder of the projects, it actually is installation folder. Then, if you want to get files from there. You need to use the "ms-appx:///" prefix in the URI.

So, if you get the `ImgPath` value from your database like this '/Images/1.jpg'. In your code, you should add `ms-appx:///Assets/` to it.

Please check my following code sample for reference:

```
<FlipView x:Name="FlipView">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImgPath}"></Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<Test> tests { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        string path = "/Images/animals.jpg";
        tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>() { new Test() {ImgPath="ms-appx:///Assets/"+path } };
        FlipView.ItemsSource = tests;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public String ImgPath { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I get this error-Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<TMD_Display.Views.MainPage.Image>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image>' TMD_Display C:\Users\alish\source\repos\TMD_Display\TMD_Display\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs 40 Active

Comment: I really cannot understand what you're doing. Why did you convert your custom class object `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<TMD_Display.Views.MainPage.Image>` to `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image>`? They're different type.

Comment: Hi. I tried the codes again. It doesn't work. The same output. And I don't understand this code-  string path = "/Images/animals.jpg"; because I want all the images to be displayed from the sql management studio.

Comment: `string path = "/Images/animals.jpg";` This line code just was my code sample for your reference.

Comment: I really did not know how to start to explain for you. It's Ok. When you call your `GetImagesAsync` method, you will get a collection. This collection has some your custom `Image` class object. Each `Image` object corresponds to a record in the database. Right?  Then, Each `Image` object has 'ImgPath' property, this property corresponds to 'ImgPath' field value of a record in the database. For example, the 'ImgPath' value is 'Images/Dashboard' and 'ImgName' is 'dashbo.png' from database. If you want to show it, you need to change the 'ImgPath' like this:

Comment: string ImgPath = "ms-appx:///Assets/"+ImgPath+"/"+ImgName;

Comment: I noted that your 'ImgPath' value in your database has online address, for example, `https://uplo...`, if this scenario, you do not need to add "ms-appx:///".

Comment: When you call `GetImagesAsync()` method, you would get a collection. Please give me a value from this collection.

Comment: Hi! Can I know what collection you're referring to? Sorry for the trouble ya :)

Comment: **When you call GetImagesAsync() method, it will return a collection to you.** I need the value of this collection.

Comment: Could you understand what I say?